# How can set array useState in loop for add more item in default array?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, state, react-hooks

I had an array with 10 item
First, I added 5 item in useState

```
const [dataList, setDataList] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
  const newArr = []
  for (var i = 0; i < 5 && i < data.length; i++) {
       newArr.push(data[i])
      }
      setDataList(newArr)
    }, [])
```

Then, when I added 5 item left, I got not expect result

```
onPress = () => {
    const newArr2 = []
    for (var i = 5; i < 10 && i < data.length; i++) {
        newArr2.push(data[i])
    }
    setDataList([...dataList, newArr2])
    console.log("dataList", dataList)
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB0JD.png

How can I push 5 item left into the useState array?
Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alternative to spread syntax could be:

```
setDataList(dataList.concat(newArr2))
```

Answer (score 3):

You are spreading your current array, but not the new one:

```
setDataList([...dataList, ...newArr2])
```